# Magento 2, Text Swatch, can't turn off "Visible on catalog pages"!

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

On Text Swatch Attributes - i have found that you cannot turn off the "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront".
For Visual swatch this does work.

even with v2.0.7, whenever switch between NO or Yes it is not saving.

Comment: Any updates please !